# Golang x509 Failed to load system roots error on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, go

I am getting an error making api calls on my local machine.

`x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided`

go env:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3.3"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3.3/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.3.3/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install go from homebrew without cgo:

```
brew remove go
brew install go --without-cgo
```

Comment: this is strange, because darwin requires cgo to get the system roots. I've confirmed a vanilla homebrew install works, is it possible you have multiple installations?

Comment: Well I was only seeing this problem when making 1000's of requests in a short period of time. Then I ran into a tcp error (which was expected)